# After using "fill_between" (matplotlib) to draw a shaded line around a line, the shaded line is moved on the y-axis

Tags: matplotlib, plot, yaxis

it's my first question on this forum and I hope it won't be a very silly one haha.
I'm preparing a plot where I've drawn two lines and now I want to add a shaded line around them to show their variability. The problem is that when I plot it the shaded lines appear shifted on the y-axis and I don't know how to solve it, any idea?

This is my code and the result plot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ornrv.png):

```
d_bas_q1 = df1["d_bas"] + df1['d_bas_q1']
d_bas_q3 = df1["d_bas"] + df1['d_bas_q3']
n_bas_q1 = df1["n_bas"] + df1['n_bas_q1']
n_bas_q3 = df1["n_bas"] + df1['n_bas_q3']


plt.figure(figsize=((10,8))) 

plt.plot(df1['band'], df1["p_bas_cond"], color='k', alpha=0.1, linewidth=2)
plt.plot(df1['band'], df1["d_bas"], color='wheat',alpha=1, linewidth=2, label='m')

plt.fill_between(range(len(df1["d_bas"])), d_bas_q1, d_bas_q3, alpha=0.4, facecolor = 'wheat') # <---- i think the problem must be here

plt.plot(df1['band'], df1["n_bas"], color='cornflowerblue', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='w')

plt.fill_between(range(len(df1["n_bas"])), n_bas_q1, n_bas_q3, alpha=0.4, facecolor = 'cornflowerblue') # <---- i think the problem must be here

plt.legend(loc="upper right") 

plt.yscale('log') 


plt.xlim([0, 10]) 
plt.ylim([plot_ymin1, plot_ymax1]) 
plt.xticks(range(0, 11, 1)) 
plt.minorticks_off()

plt.xlabel("x")

plt.ylabel('y') 

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you provide some reproducible test data?  Maybe you could try to call `plt.yscale('log')` earlier (just after `plt.figure()`)?

Comment: Or maybe you shouldn't add up `df1["d_bas"]` and `df1['d_bas_q1']`? It's hard to tell without reproducible data. Further, it looks more logical to also use `df1['band']` for the x-values of `fill_between`.